# Why did Gates McFadden leave after season 1 of TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Season 2 of *TNG*, Dr Crusher (played by McFadden) leaves, I understand, to take a position at Starfleet Medical.  I'm interested, however, in the *out of universe* reason as to **why did McFadden leave for season 2, then return for season 3?**

Comment: Agreed - this is a duplicate.  I'm not going to delete this though, as I still think 1) my answer completely addresses the question and 2) I think that if anyone has the same question this will still be a good dupe to redirect them

Comment: I've merged the two questions, so that your excellent answer is preserved in a place where it'll get more clicks and views.